# SQL Server CLR User-Defined Types: how to work via OLEDB?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, user-defined-types

How to work with  SQL Server CLR User-Defined Types in old good C++ unmanaged code via OLEDB?
Also, how to work with  Large User-Defined Types?

What are these types in OLEDB? How to interpret them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider and specify DBTYPE_UDT.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677199.aspx for more information and examples.